# How can I make sure that the two given numbers are exactly the same?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, trigonometry, numerical-value, big-numbers

I have the given numbers $n1$ and $n2$. How can I make sure that these two numbers are exactly the same? Numerically, using `{N[n1,40], N[n2,40]}`, by increasing the precision, one can check that they are the same.

```
n1:= -((1155388203804953497544704 Sin[2/9]^11)/984770902183611232881)  ;

n2:= (1/984770902183611232881)*(645922816*Cos[1/9]^11*Sin[1/9]^11*(-(6589075893012338773537049/2) + 
    339895873210749372712580*Cos[2/9] + 10352043223366063016074200*Cos[4/9] + 
    167093290604156570808000*Cos[2/3] + 4805865277064994881200000*Cos[8/9] + 
    32283270035566611600000*Cos[10/9] + 1206446636904262908000000*Cos[4/3] + 
    124077797603067000000000*Cos[16/9] + 14552037919937299638324160*Cos[2/9 - (8*Pi)/33] + 
    15803310194257891682952400*Cos[4/9 - (8*Pi)/33] + 8976670169185502571249000*
     Cos[2/3 - (8*Pi)/33] + 7850185560259061648410000*Cos[8/9 - (8*Pi)/33] + 
    3267679548688344266400000*Cos[10/9 - (8*Pi)/33] + 2300289242933457502000000*
     Cos[4/3 - (8*Pi)/33] + 624466777818913260000000*Cos[14/9 - (8*Pi)/33] + 
    350492747168580400000000*Cos[16/9 - (8*Pi)/33] + 45656332451345000000000*Cos[2 - (8*Pi)/33] + 
    20159939004490000000000*Cos[20/9 - (8*Pi)/33] - 14552037919937299638324160*
     Cos[2/9 - (7*Pi)/33] - 15803310194257891682952400*Cos[4/9 - (7*Pi)/33] - 
    8976670169185502571249000*Cos[2/3 - (7*Pi)/33] - 7850185560259061648410000*
     Cos[8/9 - (7*Pi)/33] - 3267679548688344266400000*Cos[10/9 - (7*Pi)/33] - 
    2300289242933457502000000*Cos[4/3 - (7*Pi)/33] - 624466777818913260000000*
     Cos[14/9 - (7*Pi)/33] - 350492747168580400000000*Cos[16/9 - (7*Pi)/33] - 
    45656332451345000000000*Cos[2 - (7*Pi)/33] - 20159939004490000000000*Cos[20/9 - (7*Pi)/33] + 
    339895873210749372712580*Cos[2/9 - (2*Pi)/11] + 10352043223366063016074200*
     Cos[4/9 - (2*Pi)/11] + 167093290604156570808000*Cos[2/3 - (2*Pi)/11] + 
    4805865277064994881200000*Cos[8/9 - (2*Pi)/11] + 32283270035566611600000*Cos[10/9 - (2*Pi)/11] + 
    1206446636904262908000000*Cos[4/3 - (2*Pi)/11] + 124077797603067000000000*
     Cos[16/9 - (2*Pi)/11] - 14552037919937299638324160*Cos[2/9 - (5*Pi)/33] - 
    15803310194257891682952400*Cos[4/9 - (5*Pi)/33] - 8976670169185502571249000*
     Cos[2/3 - (5*Pi)/33] - 7850185560259061648410000*Cos[8/9 - (5*Pi)/33] - 
    3267679548688344266400000*Cos[10/9 - (5*Pi)/33] - 2300289242933457502000000*
     Cos[4/3 - (5*Pi)/33] - 624466777818913260000000*Cos[14/9 - (5*Pi)/33] - 
    350492747168580400000000*Cos[16/9 - (5*Pi)/33] - 45656332451345000000000*Cos[2 - (5*Pi)/33] - 
    20159939004490000000000*Cos[20/9 - (5*Pi)/33] + 14552037919937299638324160*
     Cos[2/9 - (4*Pi)/33] + 15803310194257891682952400*Cos[4/9 - (4*Pi)/33] + 
    8976670169185502571249000*Cos[2/3 - (4*Pi)/33] + 7850185560259061648410000*
     Cos[8/9 - (4*Pi)/33] + 3267679548688344266400000*Cos[10/9 - (4*Pi)/33] + 
    2300289242933457502000000*Cos[4/3 - (4*Pi)/33] + 624466777818913260000000*
     Cos[14/9 - (4*Pi)/33] + 350492747168580400000000*Cos[16/9 - (4*Pi)/33] + 
    45656332451345000000000*Cos[2 - (4*Pi)/33] + 20159939004490000000000*Cos[20/9 - (4*Pi)/33] - 
    339895873210749372712580*Cos[2/9 - Pi/11] - 10352043223366063016074200*Cos[4/9 - Pi/11] - 
    167093290604156570808000*Cos[2/3 - Pi/11] - 4805865277064994881200000*Cos[8/9 - Pi/11] - 
    32283270035566611600000*Cos[10/9 - Pi/11] - 1206446636904262908000000*Cos[4/3 - Pi/11] - 
    124077797603067000000000*Cos[16/9 - Pi/11] + 14552037919937299638324160*Cos[2/9 - (2*Pi)/33] + 
    15803310194257891682952400*Cos[4/9 - (2*Pi)/33] + 8976670169185502571249000*
     Cos[2/3 - (2*Pi)/33] + 7850185560259061648410000*Cos[8/9 - (2*Pi)/33] + 
    3267679548688344266400000*Cos[10/9 - (2*Pi)/33] + 2300289242933457502000000*
     Cos[4/3 - (2*Pi)/33] + 624466777818913260000000*Cos[14/9 - (2*Pi)/33] + 
    350492747168580400000000*Cos[16/9 - (2*Pi)/33] + 45656332451345000000000*Cos[2 - (2*Pi)/33] + 
    20159939004490000000000*Cos[20/9 - (2*Pi)/33] - 14552037919937299638324160*Cos[2/9 - Pi/33] - 
    15803310194257891682952400*Cos[4/9 - Pi/33] - 8976670169185502571249000*Cos[2/3 - Pi/33] - 
    7850185560259061648410000*Cos[8/9 - Pi/33] - 3267679548688344266400000*Cos[10/9 - Pi/33] - 
    2300289242933457502000000*Cos[4/3 - Pi/33] - 624466777818913260000000*Cos[14/9 - Pi/33] - 
    350492747168580400000000*Cos[16/9 - Pi/33] - 45656332451345000000000*Cos[2 - Pi/33] - 
    20159939004490000000000*Cos[20/9 - Pi/33] - 14552037919937299638324160*Cos[2/9 + Pi/33] - 
    15803310194257891682952400*Cos[4/9 + Pi/33] - 8976670169185502571249000*Cos[2/3 + Pi/33] - 
    7850185560259061648410000*Cos[8/9 + Pi/33] - 3267679548688344266400000*Cos[10/9 + Pi/33] - 
    2300289242933457502000000*Cos[4/3 + Pi/33] - 624466777818913260000000*Cos[14/9 + Pi/33] - 
    350492747168580400000000*Cos[16/9 + Pi/33] - 45656332451345000000000*Cos[2 + Pi/33] - 
    20159939004490000000000*Cos[20/9 + Pi/33] + 14552037919937299638324160*Cos[2/9 + (2*Pi)/33] + 
    15803310194257891682952400*Cos[4/9 + (2*Pi)/33] + 8976670169185502571249000*
     Cos[2/3 + (2*Pi)/33] + 7850185560259061648410000*Cos[8/9 + (2*Pi)/33] + 
    3267679548688344266400000*Cos[10/9 + (2*Pi)/33] + 2300289242933457502000000*
     Cos[4/3 + (2*Pi)/33] + 624466777818913260000000*Cos[14/9 + (2*Pi)/33] + 
    350492747168580400000000*Cos[16/9 + (2*Pi)/33] + 45656332451345000000000*Cos[2 + (2*Pi)/33] + 
    20159939004490000000000*Cos[20/9 + (2*Pi)/33] - 339895873210749372712580*Cos[2/9 + Pi/11] - 
    10352043223366063016074200*Cos[4/9 + Pi/11] - 167093290604156570808000*Cos[2/3 + Pi/11] - 
    4805865277064994881200000*Cos[8/9 + Pi/11] - 32283270035566611600000*Cos[10/9 + Pi/11] - 
    1206446636904262908000000*Cos[4/3 + Pi/11] - 124077797603067000000000*Cos[16/9 + Pi/11] + 
    14552037919937299638324160*Cos[2/9 + (4*Pi)/33] + 15803310194257891682952400*
     Cos[4/9 + (4*Pi)/33] + 8976670169185502571249000*Cos[2/3 + (4*Pi)/33] + 
    7850185560259061648410000*Cos[8/9 + (4*Pi)/33] + 3267679548688344266400000*
     Cos[10/9 + (4*Pi)/33] + 2300289242933457502000000*Cos[4/3 + (4*Pi)/33] + 
    624466777818913260000000*Cos[14/9 + (4*Pi)/33] + 350492747168580400000000*
     Cos[16/9 + (4*Pi)/33] + 45656332451345000000000*Cos[2 + (4*Pi)/33] + 
    20159939004490000000000*Cos[20/9 + (4*Pi)/33] - 14552037919937299638324160*
     Cos[2/9 + (5*Pi)/33] - 15803310194257891682952400*Cos[4/9 + (5*Pi)/33] - 
    8976670169185502571249000*Cos[2/3 + (5*Pi)/33] - 7850185560259061648410000*
     Cos[8/9 + (5*Pi)/33] - 3267679548688344266400000*Cos[10/9 + (5*Pi)/33] - 
    2300289242933457502000000*Cos[4/3 + (5*Pi)/33] - 624466777818913260000000*
     Cos[14/9 + (5*Pi)/33] - 350492747168580400000000*Cos[16/9 + (5*Pi)/33] - 
    45656332451345000000000*Cos[2 + (5*Pi)/33] - 20159939004490000000000*Cos[20/9 + (5*Pi)/33] + 
    339895873210749372712580*Cos[2/9 + (2*Pi)/11] + 10352043223366063016074200*
     Cos[4/9 + (2*Pi)/11] + 167093290604156570808000*Cos[2/3 + (2*Pi)/11] + 
    4805865277064994881200000*Cos[8/9 + (2*Pi)/11] + 32283270035566611600000*Cos[10/9 + (2*Pi)/11] + 
    1206446636904262908000000*Cos[4/3 + (2*Pi)/11] + 124077797603067000000000*
     Cos[16/9 + (2*Pi)/11] - 14552037919937299638324160*Cos[2/9 + (7*Pi)/33] - 
    15803310194257891682952400*Cos[4/9 + (7*Pi)/33] - 8976670169185502571249000*
     Cos[2/3 + (7*Pi)/33] - 7850185560259061648410000*Cos[8/9 + (7*Pi)/33] - 
    3267679548688344266400000*Cos[10/9 + (7*Pi)/33] - 2300289242933457502000000*
     Cos[4/3 + (7*Pi)/33] - 624466777818913260000000*Cos[14/9 + (7*Pi)/33] - 
    350492747168580400000000*Cos[16/9 + (7*Pi)/33] - 45656332451345000000000*Cos[2 + (7*Pi)/33] - 
    20159939004490000000000*Cos[20/9 + (7*Pi)/33] + 14552037919937299638324160*
     Cos[2/9 + (8*Pi)/33] + 15803310194257891682952400*Cos[4/9 + (8*Pi)/33] + 
    8976670169185502571249000*Cos[2/3 + (8*Pi)/33] + 7850185560259061648410000*
     Cos[8/9 + (8*Pi)/33] + 3267679548688344266400000*Cos[10/9 + (8*Pi)/33] + 
    2300289242933457502000000*Cos[4/3 + (8*Pi)/33] + 624466777818913260000000*
     Cos[14/9 + (8*Pi)/33] + 350492747168580400000000*Cos[16/9 + (8*Pi)/33] + 
    45656332451345000000000*Cos[2 + (8*Pi)/33] + 20159939004490000000000*Cos[20/9 + (8*Pi)/33] - 
    19846162137536394273084800*Cos[Pi/33] + 19846162137536394273084800*Cos[(2*Pi)/33] - 
    13257093571204528085748400*Cos[Pi/11] + 19846162137536394273084800*Cos[(4*Pi)/33] - 
    19846162137536394273084800*Cos[(5*Pi)/33] + 13257093571204528085748400*Cos[(2*Pi)/11] - 
    19846162137536394273084800*Cos[(7*Pi)/33] + 19846162137536394273084800*Cos[(8*Pi)/33] + 
    339895873210749372712580*Sin[2/9 - (5*Pi)/22] + 10352043223366063016074200*
     Sin[4/9 - (5*Pi)/22] + 167093290604156570808000*Sin[2/3 - (5*Pi)/22] + 
    4805865277064994881200000*Sin[8/9 - (5*Pi)/22] + 32283270035566611600000*Sin[10/9 - (5*Pi)/22] + 
    1206446636904262908000000*Sin[4/3 - (5*Pi)/22] + 124077797603067000000000*
     Sin[16/9 - (5*Pi)/22] - 14552037919937299638324160*Sin[2/9 - (13*Pi)/66] - 
    15803310194257891682952400*Sin[4/9 - (13*Pi)/66] - 8976670169185502571249000*
     Sin[2/3 - (13*Pi)/66] - 7850185560259061648410000*Sin[8/9 - (13*Pi)/66] - 
    3267679548688344266400000*Sin[10/9 - (13*Pi)/66] - 2300289242933457502000000*
     Sin[4/3 - (13*Pi)/66] - 624466777818913260000000*Sin[14/9 - (13*Pi)/66] - 
    350492747168580400000000*Sin[16/9 - (13*Pi)/66] - 45656332451345000000000*Sin[2 - (13*Pi)/66] - 
    20159939004490000000000*Sin[20/9 - (13*Pi)/66] + 14552037919937299638324160*Sin[2/9 - Pi/6] + 
    15803310194257891682952400*Sin[4/9 - Pi/6] + 8976670169185502571249000*Sin[2/3 - Pi/6] + 
    7850185560259061648410000*Sin[8/9 - Pi/6] + 3267679548688344266400000*Sin[10/9 - Pi/6] + 
    2300289242933457502000000*Sin[4/3 - Pi/6] + 624466777818913260000000*Sin[14/9 - Pi/6] + 
    350492747168580400000000*Sin[16/9 - Pi/6] + 45656332451345000000000*Sin[2 - Pi/6] + 
    20159939004490000000000*Sin[20/9 - Pi/6] - 339895873210749372712580*Sin[2/9 - (3*Pi)/22] - 
    10352043223366063016074200*Sin[4/9 - (3*Pi)/22] - 167093290604156570808000*
     Sin[2/3 - (3*Pi)/22] - 4805865277064994881200000*Sin[8/9 - (3*Pi)/22] - 
    32283270035566611600000*Sin[10/9 - (3*Pi)/22] - 1206446636904262908000000*Sin[4/3 - (3*Pi)/22] - 
    124077797603067000000000*Sin[16/9 - (3*Pi)/22] + 14552037919937299638324160*
     Sin[2/9 - (7*Pi)/66] + 15803310194257891682952400*Sin[4/9 - (7*Pi)/66] + 
    8976670169185502571249000*Sin[2/3 - (7*Pi)/66] + 7850185560259061648410000*
     Sin[8/9 - (7*Pi)/66] + 3267679548688344266400000*Sin[10/9 - (7*Pi)/66] + 
    2300289242933457502000000*Sin[4/3 - (7*Pi)/66] + 624466777818913260000000*
     Sin[14/9 - (7*Pi)/66] + 350492747168580400000000*Sin[16/9 - (7*Pi)/66] + 
    45656332451345000000000*Sin[2 - (7*Pi)/66] + 20159939004490000000000*Sin[20/9 - (7*Pi)/66] - 
    14552037919937299638324160*Sin[2/9 - (5*Pi)/66] - 15803310194257891682952400*
     Sin[4/9 - (5*Pi)/66] - 8976670169185502571249000*Sin[2/3 - (5*Pi)/66] - 
    7850185560259061648410000*Sin[8/9 - (5*Pi)/66] - 3267679548688344266400000*
     Sin[10/9 - (5*Pi)/66] - 2300289242933457502000000*Sin[4/3 - (5*Pi)/66] - 
    624466777818913260000000*Sin[14/9 - (5*Pi)/66] - 350492747168580400000000*
     Sin[16/9 - (5*Pi)/66] - 45656332451345000000000*Sin[2 - (5*Pi)/66] - 
    20159939004490000000000*Sin[20/9 - (5*Pi)/66] + 339895873210749372712580*Sin[2/9 - Pi/22] + 
    10352043223366063016074200*Sin[4/9 - Pi/22] + 167093290604156570808000*Sin[2/3 - Pi/22] + 
    4805865277064994881200000*Sin[8/9 - Pi/22] + 32283270035566611600000*Sin[10/9 - Pi/22] + 
    1206446636904262908000000*Sin[4/3 - Pi/22] + 124077797603067000000000*Sin[16/9 - Pi/22] - 
    14552037919937299638324160*Sin[2/9 - Pi/66] - 15803310194257891682952400*Sin[4/9 - Pi/66] - 
    8976670169185502571249000*Sin[2/3 - Pi/66] - 7850185560259061648410000*Sin[8/9 - Pi/66] - 
    3267679548688344266400000*Sin[10/9 - Pi/66] - 2300289242933457502000000*Sin[4/3 - Pi/66] - 
    624466777818913260000000*Sin[14/9 - Pi/66] - 350492747168580400000000*Sin[16/9 - Pi/66] - 
    45656332451345000000000*Sin[2 - Pi/66] - 20159939004490000000000*Sin[20/9 - Pi/66] + 
    14552037919937299638324160*Sin[2/9 + Pi/66] + 15803310194257891682952400*Sin[4/9 + Pi/66] + 
    8976670169185502571249000*Sin[2/3 + Pi/66] + 7850185560259061648410000*Sin[8/9 + Pi/66] + 
    3267679548688344266400000*Sin[10/9 + Pi/66] + 2300289242933457502000000*Sin[4/3 + Pi/66] + 
    624466777818913260000000*Sin[14/9 + Pi/66] + 350492747168580400000000*Sin[16/9 + Pi/66] + 
    45656332451345000000000*Sin[2 + Pi/66] + 20159939004490000000000*Sin[20/9 + Pi/66] - 
    339895873210749372712580*Sin[2/9 + Pi/22] - 10352043223366063016074200*Sin[4/9 + Pi/22] - 
    167093290604156570808000*Sin[2/3 + Pi/22] - 4805865277064994881200000*Sin[8/9 + Pi/22] - 
    32283270035566611600000*Sin[10/9 + Pi/22] - 1206446636904262908000000*Sin[4/3 + Pi/22] - 
    124077797603067000000000*Sin[16/9 + Pi/22] + 14552037919937299638324160*Sin[2/9 + (5*Pi)/66] + 
    15803310194257891682952400*Sin[4/9 + (5*Pi)/66] + 8976670169185502571249000*
     Sin[2/3 + (5*Pi)/66] + 7850185560259061648410000*Sin[8/9 + (5*Pi)/66] + 
    3267679548688344266400000*Sin[10/9 + (5*Pi)/66] + 2300289242933457502000000*
     Sin[4/3 + (5*Pi)/66] + 624466777818913260000000*Sin[14/9 + (5*Pi)/66] + 
    350492747168580400000000*Sin[16/9 + (5*Pi)/66] + 45656332451345000000000*Sin[2 + (5*Pi)/66] + 
    20159939004490000000000*Sin[20/9 + (5*Pi)/66] - 14552037919937299638324160*
     Sin[2/9 + (7*Pi)/66] - 15803310194257891682952400*Sin[4/9 + (7*Pi)/66] - 
    8976670169185502571249000*Sin[2/3 + (7*Pi)/66] - 7850185560259061648410000*
     Sin[8/9 + (7*Pi)/66] - 3267679548688344266400000*Sin[10/9 + (7*Pi)/66] - 
    2300289242933457502000000*Sin[4/3 + (7*Pi)/66] - 624466777818913260000000*
     Sin[14/9 + (7*Pi)/66] - 350492747168580400000000*Sin[16/9 + (7*Pi)/66] - 
    45656332451345000000000*Sin[2 + (7*Pi)/66] - 20159939004490000000000*Sin[20/9 + (7*Pi)/66] + 
    339895873210749372712580*Sin[2/9 + (3*Pi)/22] + 10352043223366063016074200*
     Sin[4/9 + (3*Pi)/22] + 167093290604156570808000*Sin[2/3 + (3*Pi)/22] + 
    4805865277064994881200000*Sin[8/9 + (3*Pi)/22] + 32283270035566611600000*Sin[10/9 + (3*Pi)/22] + 
    1206446636904262908000000*Sin[4/3 + (3*Pi)/22] + 124077797603067000000000*
     Sin[16/9 + (3*Pi)/22] - 14552037919937299638324160*Sin[2/9 + Pi/6] - 
    15803310194257891682952400*Sin[4/9 + Pi/6] - 8976670169185502571249000*Sin[2/3 + Pi/6] - 
    7850185560259061648410000*Sin[8/9 + Pi/6] - 3267679548688344266400000*Sin[10/9 + Pi/6] - 
    2300289242933457502000000*Sin[4/3 + Pi/6] - 624466777818913260000000*Sin[14/9 + Pi/6] - 
    350492747168580400000000*Sin[16/9 + Pi/6] - 45656332451345000000000*Sin[2 + Pi/6] - 
    20159939004490000000000*Sin[20/9 + Pi/6] + 14552037919937299638324160*Sin[2/9 + (13*Pi)/66] + 
    15803310194257891682952400*Sin[4/9 + (13*Pi)/66] + 8976670169185502571249000*
     Sin[2/3 + (13*Pi)/66] + 7850185560259061648410000*Sin[8/9 + (13*Pi)/66] + 
    3267679548688344266400000*Sin[10/9 + (13*Pi)/66] + 2300289242933457502000000*
     Sin[4/3 + (13*Pi)/66] + 624466777818913260000000*Sin[14/9 + (13*Pi)/66] + 
    350492747168580400000000*Sin[16/9 + (13*Pi)/66] + 45656332451345000000000*Sin[2 + (13*Pi)/66] + 
    20159939004490000000000*Sin[20/9 + (13*Pi)/66] - 339895873210749372712580*Sin[2/9 + (5*Pi)/22] - 
    10352043223366063016074200*Sin[4/9 + (5*Pi)/22] - 167093290604156570808000*
     Sin[2/3 + (5*Pi)/22] - 4805865277064994881200000*Sin[8/9 + (5*Pi)/22] - 
    32283270035566611600000*Sin[10/9 + (5*Pi)/22] - 1206446636904262908000000*Sin[4/3 + (5*Pi)/22] - 
    124077797603067000000000*Sin[16/9 + (5*Pi)/22] + 19846162137536394273084800*Sin[Pi/66] - 
    13257093571204528085748400*Sin[Pi/22] + 19846162137536394273084800*Sin[(5*Pi)/66] - 
    19846162137536394273084800*Sin[(7*Pi)/66] + 13257093571204528085748400*Sin[(3*Pi)/22] + 
    19846162137536394273084800*Sin[(13*Pi)/66] - 13257093571204528085748400*Sin[(5*Pi)/22]))   ;
```

Comment: `n1 - n2 // TrigToExp // Simplify // RootReduce // AbsoluteTiming` takes a little over 12 seconds to return `0`

Comment: To help people searching for the same question and maybe to make the suggestions by stack exchange more helpful when you write the title of the question, you can include specifications about your question in the title. For example specifying that the two numbers involve trigonometric functions.

Comment: Purely out of curiosity and interest but what field/application is this used in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Code**

(explanation below)

```
n2[[1 ;; 3]]*n2[[4]] == n2
```

`(* True *)`

```
n2[[1 ;; 3]]*
  Collect[TrigExpand[n2[[4]]], {Cos[2/9], Sin[2/9]}, 
   RootReduce@*ToRadicals] /. Cos[s_] :> Sin[2*s]/(2*Sin[s])
```

$$-\frac{1155388203804953497544704 \sin ^{11}\left(\frac{2}{9}\right)}{984770902183611232881}$$

(same as n1)

**timing** : 0.9 seconds.

---

**Topics in the answer below** :

- How to find terms with similar structure in a big expression ?

In this example we can use (`ExpressionTree` introduced in 2021 (version 12.3) (in this answer, `expression=n2[[4]]`):

```
Gather[Cases[expression, #, All], 
   IsomorphicGraphQ[Graph@ExpressionTree[#1], 
     Graph@ExpressionTree[#2]] &] & /@ {Cos[_], Sin[_]}
```

- How to force cancellations to occur when we think they should ?

(explanation below) In this particular example I isolated `Cos[2/9]` and `Sin[2/9]` (can be found with the code above) because they are not special in any way. I do not expect their properties to lead to cancellations so I factored them and let the other terms cancel out. I used:

```
Collect[expression //TrigExpand,{Cos[2/9], Sin[2/9]}, RootReduce@*ToRadicals]
```

---

**Answer, part 1**

If a complicated expression with many terms simplifies to a simple expression then it is probably because there are many similar terms or a lot of cancellations can occur. The purpose of this answer is to highlight the cancellations and simplify the expression quickly.

First, notice that the factor in `n2` is similar to `n1`:

n1 :

$$-\frac{1155388203804953497544704 \sin ^{11}\left(\frac{2}{9}\right)}{984770902183611232881}$$

`n2` is a product of 4 factors which can be checked using `Head[n2]` and `Level[n2, 1]`. The last one is the lengthy sum and the first 3 are similar to `n1`

`n2[[1 ;; 3]]` :

$$\frac{645922816 \sin ^{11}\left(\frac{1}{9}\right) \cos ^{11}\left(\frac{1}{9}\right)}{984770902183611232881}$$

Notice then that using $2 \sin (\theta ) \cos (\theta )= \sin (2 \theta )$ that the two expressions are the same up to a rational factor. If `n1` and `n2` are equal, that means that the complicated sum of trigonometric functions is in fact rational suggesting possible cancellations between terms. This is what happens as is shown below.

---

**Answer, part 2**

In the light of the above discussion, the analysis is restricted to `n2[[4]]` which represents the complicated sum.

First we investigate the structure of the expression by checking the different types of trigonometric functions that appear. There are many and we do not need to know all the details so we can pick just one representative for each structure:

```
DeleteDuplicates[Cases[n2[[4]], #, All], 
   IsomorphicGraphQ[Graph@ExpressionTree[#1], 
     Graph@ExpressionTree[#2]] &] & /@ {Cos[_], Sin[_]}
```

$$\left\{\left\{\cos \left(\frac{2}{9}\right),\cos \left(\frac{2}{9}-\frac{8 \pi }{33}\right),\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{33}\right)\right\},\left\{\sin \left(\frac{2}{9}-\frac{5 \pi }{22}\right),\sin \left(\frac{\pi }{66}\right)\right\}\right\}$$

The terms that have arguments where $\pi$ multiplies a rational are somewhat special as they are the real and imaginary parts of powers of roots of unity ($w^p=1$) which are known to cancel out when you sum them (because they represent symmetric polygons around the origin or more analytically, because of the root/coefficient relationship of polynomial equations [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) ).

The terms that have rational arguments are not special and so they should cancel out to obtain a rational result in the end. To force this cancellation to occur we rewrite the expression as a multivariate polynomial of these non special terms such that, other than the "constant term" each coefficient should be equal to zero.

The terms like $\cos \left(\frac{2}{9}-\frac{8 \pi }{33}\right)$ have to be expanded as they also contain `Cos` and `Sin` of rational arguments when trig expanded. To find all the trigonometric functions with rational arguments we use:

```
DeleteDuplicates[Cases[n2[[4]] // TrigExpand, #, All]] & /@ {Cos[_], 
  Sin[_]}
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 \cos \left(\frac{2}{9}\right) & \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{33}\right) & \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{66}\right) & \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{22}\right) \\
 \sin \left(\frac{2}{9}\right) & \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{66}\right) & \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{33}\right) & \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{22}\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Hence, it sufficient to isolate the terms in `Cos[2/9]` and `Sin[2/9]`. Each coefficient is then simplified using `RootReduce@*ToRadicals`:

```
Collect[TrigExpand[n2[[4]]], {Cos[2/9], Sin[2/9]}, 
 RootReduce@*ToRadicals]
```

`(* -(7326680472586200649/2) *)`